# uinavigation bar large title lingers during transition to a new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationbar

In ViewController A, I set `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`
When I push `navigationController` to ViewController B

In ViewController B viewDidLoad I set `navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false`

During the transition, the large title still lingers for awhile. How do I remove this and have a transition similar to WhatsApp?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8NdC.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAoLm.png